# enableGesture(); error on Kinect SimpleOpenNI

Tags: kinect, processing, simple-openni

everyone. I'm have a problem and i don't no how to solve it. I try to make some tutorials with Hand click on Processing, and always happened the same error, the function enableGesture(); does not exist. What I can do? Can someone Help me?
Thank You

Comment: which version of simpleopenni are you using?

Answer (score 1):

whether it's

`kinect.enableGesture();`

or

`context.enableGesture();`

it doesn't matter it just depends on the variable your code chose in this line

```
SimpleOpenNI 'variable name here' = new SimpleOpenNI(this);
```

The function `enableGesture();` is out of date

All you have to do is change `enableGesture();` to `startGesture(SimpleOpenNI."gesture");`

Where "gesture" can be either
GESTURE_CLICK, GESTURE_HAND_RAISE or GESTURE_WAVE

And it is most likely that you will encounter other out of date functions such as:

`enableHands();` which is now `enableHand();`

`addGesture(String);` which is now `startGesture(SimpleOpenNI."gesture");`

`removeGesture(String);` which is now `endGesture(SimpleOpenNI."gesture");`

`startTrackingHands(PVector);` which is now `startTrackingHand(PVector);`

Hope this Helps
- E.B.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is because of the simpleopenni version you are using. try using

```
SimpleOpenNI context = new SimpleOpenNI(this); 
context.startGesture(SimpleOpenNI.GESTURE_CLICK);
//change constant for other gestures
```